# Is it possible for buck boost converter to output -48V with +12V input?

Tags: buck, boost, converter

I have a school task for creating a Buck Boost converter that takes `12V` and outputs `-48V`. I have done some digging and couldn't find my answer since I could only find converters that give a number lower than the input number (like in my case I can get `-6V` with my calculations but not lower that `-12V`).

Is this thing even possible only by creating a conventional converter?

Comment: Is all about the duty cycle of the command.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is definitely possible.  Here is a hint:

[image]

Look at this carefully.  Start with the switch open and 0 inductor current.  Then consider what happens if the switch is closed for a while, then what happens when the switch is opened after that.

At the time the switch is opened, what, if anything, is limiting the voltage at the left end of the inductor?

After adding the rest of the parts to make a actual power supply out of this, consider the effect of duty cycle (the fraction of time the switch is closed).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need to search for 'inverting buck boost'?

Think about what's going on if you have a grounded inductor. 'Charge it up' through a switch from the +ve supply. Then open the switch. Current is flowing into the inductor, so it continues to flow in, and drives the output -ve. As far -ve as you like. Job done, set the switching times to stabilise the voltage.

Answer (score 2):

A fly back design is probably best suited to what you need. A conventional flyback design usually creates a positive voltage but, because the circuit uses a transformer, the output can be wired to produce a negative voltage very simply: -

[image]

This one is only -9V and runs from +5V but the transformer turns ratio can be changed to create a bigger step-up inverted voltage. Just find a 12V to 48V flyback circuit and swap the output connections like the above does: -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want negative output volts which generally is not the case then there is the CUK topology which is accepted and well documented .In its classical form it uses 2 inductors .There are versions that wind both inductors on one core .Normal hard switch peak current mode chips can drive this circuit.